# Capture "ReturnUrl" for redirection

Tags: asp.net

I am using Forms Authentication. When my Form timesout I get the URL:

```
http://XXXXXX/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSessionExpired.aspx
```

Is there a way to say if url contains "ReturnUrL" redirect to sessiontimeout.aspx?
I have tried putting this in my global.asax but it does not work. It still goes to:
`http://XXXXXX/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSessionExpired.aspx`, which is my login page.

Please help.

Comment: in login.aspx could you not do 
    `if(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
    //do stuff`

Answer (score 0):

You can capture `ReturnUrl` and it's value in the **`Request.QueryString`** variables in your login.aspx.

I guess you are using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` If you want to check first and decide where to redirect yourself; you should use **`SetAuthCookie`** method of `FormsAuthentication`. Then you can redirect the page yourself.

Also, there is a **`FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl`** method. The documentation remarks "*You can use this method when you want to perform the redirect in your application code instead of using the RedirectFromLoginPage method.*" See **[documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.getredirecturl.aspx)**.